# Table rows and cells index javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

my problem is :

> " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined "

i have one table and need 2 for access data in td table.
console.log for test. (loop problem)

```js
var gameBoard = document.getElementById("game-board");
for (var i=14; i>=0; i--)
{
   for(var j=5; j>=0; j--)
      console.log(gameBoard.rows[i+1].cells[j+1].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table id="game-board" class="game-board">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="col-1-1"></td>
                            <td id="col-1-2"></td>
                            <td id="col-1-3"></td>
                            <td id="col-1-4"></td>
                            <td id="col-1-5"></td>
                            <td id="col-1-6"></td>
                        </tr>
....
....
....

                        <tr>
                            <td id="col-15-1"></td>
                            <td id="col-15-2"></td>
                            <td id="col-15-3"></td>
                            <td id="col-15-4"></td>
                            <td id="col-15-5"></td>
                            <td id="col-15-6"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

please help me.!!

Comment: if there're 15 rows (as I guess), when i = 14, `gameBoard.rows[i+1]`  is undefined definitely. Note that `index` starts from 0, not 1.
It seems using those fixed values like `14` and `5` is not safe at all. In your case, try to use `rows.length` and `cells.length` instead.

Comment: i=gameBoard.rows.length and j=gameBoard.rows[i].cells.length but have this error "Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined"

Comment: It should be `i=gameBoard.rows.length - 1` and `j = gameBoard.rows[i].cells.length - 1`. And just need to use `console.log(gameBoard.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML)`

Comment: thank you so much :)))))))))